# Why is the newline character not working when I draw a string within -drawRect:?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

the Newline character is not working in draw rect of UIView? can anyone help?

```
 - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
UIFont * f = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];
[[UIColor darkGrayColor] set];
 CGRect b = [self bounds];

NSString * text = @"hi \nr u";

CGSize sz = CGSizeMake(150,200);

CGContextScaleCTM(context, b.size.width/sz.width, b.size.height/sz.height);
[text drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(0,0) withFont:f];
```

}

Answer (score 4):

Consider using `drawInRect:withFont:` instead of `drawAtPoint:withFont:`, as the latter only supports a single line of text.